# IOS7 - SLComposeView Controller - Error Posting to twitter - Cannot Post To Twitter - connection error

Tags: ios, twitter

When i am trying to post on to twitter it shows me an error message which says "Cannot send tweet because the connection to twitter failed"

```
 if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{
    SLComposeViewController *composeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

    if (composeViewController)
    {
        NSString *initialTextString = @"Test";

        [composeViewController setInitialText:initialTextString];

        [composeViewController setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result)
        {
            if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultDone)
            {
                NSLog(@"Posted");
                UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Posted on Twitter" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert1 show];
                [self performSelector:@selector(dismiss:) withObject:alert1 afterDelay:1.0];

            }
            else if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
            {
                NSLog(@"Post Cancelled");

            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Post Failed");

            }
        }];
        [self presentViewController:composeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that shows us what you have tried and what could be worng.

Comment: Please check the above code.